# Removing/Changing "none" from column in Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a Data Frame and I'm trying to recode some of the contents of a column. I want to create three categories (w, x, y) out of several others.
It works fine for most of the data. But I can't get it to recode the "none"s out of it.

```
df<- df%>% mutate(col=recode(col, 
                         "a" = "y",
                         "b" = "y",
                         "none" = "y"))
```

When I run it, it works for a and b. But the nones remain.

```
summary(df$col)

   w          x          y         none  
 81925      31166      16941      34536
```

I also tried the following. But that just changed all of the columns to y, eventough I was quite convinced it worked on other occacions for me.

```
df$col <- df$col[df$col == "none"] <- "y"
```

How do I get the nones to be "y"?

P.S.: I hope the formatting is sufficent. First time asking and a beginner here on stackoverflow and in R.

Comment: If you can share the first 10 or so rows of your data (use `dput`), I could supplement my answer with an explanation. Currently, with my fake data below, your code seems to work (missing a `)` at the end of your `mutate()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `case_when`

```
df %>% mutate(col=case_when(
  col %in% c("a", "b", "none")~"y",
  col %in% c("s", "t", "u")~"x",
  col %in% c("f", "g", "h")~"w",
  TRUE~"other_letter"
)) %>% 
  count(col)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  col              n
  <chr>        <int>
1 other_letter   665
2 w              132
3 x              108
4 y               95
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  col = factor(sample(c(1:26, NA), 1000, replace=T),labels = c(letters,"none"), exclude=F)
)

> df %>% count(col) %>% as.data.frame()
    col  n
1     a 31
2     b 33
3     c 39
4     d 31
5     e 31
6     f 36
7     g 45
8     h 51
9     i 35
10    j 52
11    k 39
12    l 32
13    m 31
14    n 37
15    o 35
16    p 32
17    q 36
18    r 35
19    s 35
20    t 38
21    u 35
22    v 35
23    w 46
24    x 37
25    y 46
26    z 36
27 none 31
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that only creates NAs and renames the other column names into col.theirName.

Comment: again, I'll need to see your data, (please use `dput`) because the code above works.

Comment: Sorry I did not answer. I solved it myself. Their was a space behind the name of the entries i wanted to change. Since I did not create that, it just wasn't visible for me. Very stupid, but my mistake.  So for everyone having a simliar problem: Look for spaces! :D But thanks for trying. :)